# how to view laser data and point cloud in rviz at same time?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

am using rviz to visualize a point cloud and some sick laser data but i'm unable to view both at the same time as i need to change the fixed and target frame from /laser (for laser data) to /world (for point cloud).

how can i view both laser data and point cloud at same time?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28620/how-to-view-laser-data-and-point-cloud-in-rviz-at-same-time?/) by [liquidmonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/1325/liquidmonkey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2012-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ability to see both depends on the transform from "laser" to "world". If the transform is large, you won't be able to see both simultaneously. If the transform is small enough, you should be able to see both on the same screen.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-02-27**:
And if the transform is missing, rviz won't display both properly. You then might want to use the `static_transform_publisher`.